# Why can't I access a method in Sencha Touch JavaScript config object from handler?

Tags: function, scope, sencha-touch, handler

This is probably a lack of understanding of JavaScript scope, but why cannot I access this.onLoginTap() from within the Panel items element when the button is pressed. I get an error stating that this.onLoginTap does not exist. My solution for the moment will be to move the declaration of the items into the initComponent method, but I'm still wondering why I can't access this method.

Thanks,

Philip

```
app.myView = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {       
    fullscreen: true,
    scroll: 'vertical',
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox'
    },        

    items: [{
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox'
            },
            items: [ {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Log In',
                ui: 'confirm',
                handler: function() {
                   this.onLoginTap(); // this.onLoginTap is undefined here at runtime.
                }
            }]
        }],

        // Controller Dispatchers
        onLoginTap: function() {
            console.log('onLoginTap');
        },

        initComponent: function() {
            app.myView.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
        }                
    });

    Ext.reg('myView', app.myView);
```

Answer (score 3):

The "this" pointer is indeed not pointing to the button at the moment of execution.

But most importantly, here are some solutions:

SOLUTION 1:

Check the documentation for the handler:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.Button-cfg-handler

You'll see that you can get the actual button instance from the handler function:

```
handler: function(button, event) {
    var parent = button.ownerCt; // get your main panel, the owner of the button
    parent.onLoginTap();
}
```

I haven't tested the code, but the basic idea should be clear.

SOLUTION 2:

- Remove the handler from the config
- Assign the handler in initComponent:

  ```
   // Get the button and add a listener to it:
   this.items.get(0).addListener('tap', this.onLoginTap);
  ```

SOLUTION 3:

Same as solution 2, except that you assign the handlers/listeners from within the controller.
The controller manages the panel/view, so it makes sense that it binds all the logic together for it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Solution 1 does not work, so I'm still stumped to the scoping question. I've tried it and the button.ownerCt does not contain the method. Solution 2 and 3 are reasonable, however, personally, I prefer to have the handler call attached where the ui component is defined so that I can see what is going to what. However, I'm open to persuasion on this one ;-) Need to think some more about this... Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
items: [ {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Log In',
            ui: 'confirm',

            handler: function() {
               this.up('panel').onLoginTap(); // this.onLoginTap is undefined here at runtime.
            }
        }]
```

Edit: Just encountered same situation - mine is an MVC setup and my button is in a formpanel. I was able to access the main view using this.up('formpanel') so the above might work for you (I also did not set the scope in the button as that did not work with it)

Comment: Nope, 'this' refers to DOMWindow and not the actual view class. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @PhilipMurphy Than you have something else wired up wrong.  The handler config calls the tap event of the button.  The Sencha docs clearly show that the 'this' within the tap event refers to the button itself.  Yashua's code should work.  However you could try "this.parent.onLoginTap()" instead and see if that works better.